# How to read a .ipynb in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a .ipynb and Im trying to open it in VS code but I see it like this

[image: ipynb file content]

Also I try to import the file from VS code an I got this error

[image: error msg]

Everything is in one line and I cannot see it as a Jupiter Notebook. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Enter image description here

Comment: This reference may help you https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support